# Multivariate mcmcGLMM - pMCMC for interaction

Tags: multivariate-analysis, interaction, lme4-nlme

I want to test my  linear mixed effect model for interactions using MCMCglmm:

```
MCMCglmm(cbind(dv1, dv2, dv3, dv4) ~ time*treat*gen*age,
+ family=c("poisson","gaussian","poisson","gaussian"), 
+ random=~individual, data=mydata)
```

Giving the following error:

```
Error in MCMCglmm(cbind(dv1, dv2, dv3, dv4) ~ time * treat * :
R-structure miss-specified: each residual must be unique to a data point
```

Using just one dependent variable, the MCMCglmm works just fine.
dv1 is count data,
dv2 is continous numeric,
dv3 is count data,
dv4 is continous numeric,
individual is a group of 20 individuals with repeated measures
time is a fixed effect with 7 timepoints per individual
gen is a factor of 2
treat is a factor of 2
age is a factor of 2 (old and young)

Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an issue with the residual covariance structure specification.

```
rcov = ~us(trait):units
```

Additionally, since you are measuring several traits on the same individual it might be interesting to look at the covariance of the different variables using

```
random = ~us(trait):individual
```

Having a look at the model m5a.2, p91 in [MCMCglmm Course notes from Hadfield](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/CourseNotes.pdf) would probably help.